# Flexbox - IE 10-11 is not making columns equal width regardless of content

Tags: css

This method works in Chrome, Safari and FF however does not work in IE.

I have a table layout that I need the widths to equal the same width regardless of the content inside. To do this in the other browsers I have added the property flex: 1 1 0; to the element.

However when I look at this in IE it is still mis-aligned. I have read that the default value in IE is different so I tried adding the value 1 0 0 instead to see if this would change things with no success.

Has anyone else had a similar problem with flex: 1; that they have fixed by using a prefix?

ta

Comment: Please share your current css and html so that we can see what is going on.

Comment: I can't see the code or link to the fiddle :P

Answer (score 0):

use property

```
justify-content: flex-start | flex-end | center | space-between | space-around

.flex-item {
  justify-content: space-between; or /* space-around */
}
```

[Refer](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/j/justify-content/)